# What is the running time of the following code?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

Isn't the running time simply n-i, which is just O(n)?  Or am I not considering everything in this situation?

```
i <- c
while i < n do
i <- i*c
end while
```

Comment: What if c=1 and n>1?

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be logarithm with the base of c from n ?

You are basically multiplying i until it reaches the value of n.

Answer (score 2):

The running time of this algorithm is **O(log n)**. It will not be n-i because you are not incrementing the loop counter by adding or subtracting a value. Rather you are incrementing the loop counter by c so you are scaling it up by c in every iterations. So the maximum number of iterations it can go is log_c(n).